# How to insert dynamically a text in an object "angular"?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to be able to select a specific object and enter a text in it 'dynamically' in Angular.

App file:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

$scope.persons = [
{
    name: "Kevin",
    lastName: "Cris",
    mottos : [
        {
            motto: "Holy Moly!"
        }
    ],
},
{
    name: "Tres",
    lastName: "Yepo",
    mottos : [
        {
            motto: "Crispy!"
        }
    ],
},
{
    name: "Prosi",
    lastName: "Nani",
    mottos : [
        {
            motto: "I love this!"
        }
    ],
}
];

}]);
```

I can insert a text in the object in array[1]:

```
$scope.addMotto = function(){
    $scope.persons[1].mottos.push({
        motto: $scope.enterMotto
    });
};
```

But, how could I be able to add **motto** to a person object each time?

To be more clear: What I am trying to do is: Select a person and add motto.
What I can't figure out is: How to create selection of a person object and add on selected object a text.

Html file:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<section ng-repeat="person in persons">

    <p class="header">Persons --</p>

    <p>Name: {{person.name}}</p>
    <p>lastName: {{person.lastName}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="shoutOut in person.mottos" class="motto">Motto: {{shoutOut.motto}} </p>

</section>
<p ng-repet="newMotto in persons.mottos">Your Motto: {{newMotto.motto}} </p>

<p>Enter Motto:<input type="text" ng-model="enterMotto" /></p>


<button ng-click="addMotto()">Submit </button>

</div><!--myCtrl-->
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/9eau9dq2/

Comment: Do you want to add `motto` to each of your person object ?

Comment: I just want to add motto to selected person..So: select a person and add motto..(not a motto for each person..) thank you!

Comment: I could not see any code where you are selecting a person before adding a motto to it

Comment: That was the problem that I couldn't find because:) How do I select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add to each of the person object, here is what you should do - http://jsfiddle.net/k8o8x60w/

```
$scope.addMotto = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.persons, function(item, i){
        item.mottos.push({motto: $scope.enterMotto});
    });
};
```

If you want to add to the selected person object, you will need to keep the selected id with you and update the id whenever a different person is selected and update his motto accordingly.

You could provide a select box like this to allow user to select a person to which you would want to add a motto

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="person in persons" value="{{person.name}}">{{ person.name }} {{ person.lastName }}</option>
</select>
```

and update your method to...

```
 $scope.addMotto = function () {
     angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (item, i) {
         if (item.name == $scope.selectedperson) {
             item.mottos.push({
                 motto: $scope.enterMotto
             });
         }
     });
 };
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k8o8x60w/1/

Note: Would strongly advice you to use some id too in the person object.

Answer (score 1):

i updated your fiddle with some working code!
http://jsfiddle.net/9eau9dq2/1/

```
You could also use a select box for sure, but that is really similar anyways ;-)
```

Hope that helps!
Jan

Comment: That works fine indeed!:) However the answer of Yasser was what I wanted to make, I guess.